# Javascript causing all HTML to be replaced by string

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

(I'm relatively new to JS, hence the silly mistakes you'll  probably see me make. Thank you.)

I'm not sure why this happens, especially when I'm not telling the page to add or remove any elements at all. But basically, when I run certain scripts the entire screen goes blank except for a random value I used somewhere in the code.

An example of this which would work anywhere is calling `prompt()` without saving the result as a variable (or just running something like `javascript:"string"`). Now that's partially understandable; the page has no idea what to do with the returned value so it just displays it. Whatever.

However, the same thing occurs running this script (which is indeed a primitive Scatter hack for Quizlet). Upon running, it goes through all the Scatter terms, one by one, alerts the user with the HTML content, and changes the location of the box. However, after the last alert is closed, the entire screen turns white and displays "300px" in the top-left of the screen. Commenting out line 5 (`// x[i].style.left = "300px";`) just makes it display "600px" instead.

This seems like a simple enough script... What is going on here?

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("scatterTermSide lang-en TermText");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    alert("Found item \"" + x[i].innerHTML + "\".");
    x[i].style.left = "600px";
    x[i].style.top = "300px";
}
```

Eventually I'm going to extend this so it moves the non-English tiles and the tiles you've hovered over with your mouse as well (yes, they permanently change the class name after you hover), but that won't be able to happen until I get over this issue.
The Scatter game I'm running this on can be found [here](https://quizlet.com/82823565/scatter).

Comment: In which browser does this problem occur?

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  How are you executing your code block?

Comment: Please provide a code sample that allows duplication of the problem. See item #2 in off topic questions section of [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Roberto I didn't read that page but coincidentally I did provide an example which produces the same effect; if you are incapable of filling in blanks you can simply copy and paste the following into your URL bar and press Enter - javascript:"sample string";

Comment: @fermats_last_nerve I have the code saved as a bookmarklet which I click on to run (using the format "javascript:[code here...]").

Comment: @Tim 64-bit Chrome 48.0.2564.116 (Official Build), revision 0. Running on Chrome OS 7647.84.0 (Official Build) stable-channel parrot_ivb; Javascript is currently V8 4.8.271.20.

Comment: Does the console give you any helpful information when you check it?

Comment: @JoeL None that I can see. There's two errors that appear when the page loads, one of them says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of null" and the other simply states and it can't load an ad (because I blocked it). Nothing new appears after I run the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your bookmarklet is properly uri-encoded.  Use a tool like http://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/ to make sure it is.  When I do this, your code works fine on the provided Scatter Quiz.

The end product is this:

`javascript:(function()%7Bvar%20x%20%3D%20document.getElementsByClassName(%22scatterTermSide%20lang-en%20TermText%22)%3B%20for%20(i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20x.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%20alert(%22Found%20item%20%5C%22%22%20%2B%20x%5Bi%5D.innerHTML%20%2B%20%22%5C%22.%22)%3B%20x%5Bi%5D.style.left%20%3D%20%22600px%22%3B%20x%5Bi%5D.style.top%20%3D%20%22300px%22%3B%20%7D%7D)()`

Comment: Oddly enough, using the bookmarklet encoder fixes the issue. I'm not sure why though, it seems like all the other bookmarklets I've written have worked without encoding... Anyway, marking this as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds like a syntax error. You're getting results that shouldn't really be possible based on the code you have written. For me, this is a red flag that there is a missing } or similar problem somewhere in the code. I recommend commenting out blocks of code until you can remove the issue. There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted here, works great in a fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for telling me that something is wrong. Could you please tell me something helpful (e.g. what is wrong).

Comment: sorry dude, can't see your code. I can only confirm that the piece of code you provided is not the problem.

Comment: The piece of code I provided is the entirety of my script so far.

Comment: did you place your script in a HTML page? include that. Here's the fiddle of your code working. https://jsfiddle.net/8k5a2xcx/

Comment: Read the other answers and comments on this page for context. I already stated that I was running this from a bookmarket on a page built by someone else... you can find the link in the Original Post, look through the HTML all you wish.